# Nested foreach() in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need some help with nested `foreach`.

This is my code:

```
$program = $_POST['program'];
$licence = $_POST['licence'];
    foreach($program as $p){
        foreach($licence as $l){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO programs (pcname, program, licence) VALUES ('". $pcname ."', '". $p ."', '". $l ."')");

  }
}
```

This doesn't work and I know why. But I cannot find a way to fix the issue. The issue is, that it is going through all the values in the inside `foreach`, then is is going through them all, all over again for the next value in the outside `foreach`.

This probably wasn't explained very well, but hopefully you can understand what I am doing in trying to achieve, and to help me out.

Comment: What behavior do you expect, or want?

Comment: Is the $program/$licence an array? I think not, as the $_POST values are strings.

Comment: @Voitcus they are arrays, and not strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your two arrays have a  1:1 mapping between their elements, say. 5 each, then your nested loops are going to produce 25 insert calls. You need to use the keys from one array to refer to the other:

```
foreach($program as $key => $p) {
    $l = $license[$key];
    mysql_query(...);
}
```

and note that you are WIDE open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: This worked like a charm, worked exactly as I wanted it to, and yes I know I am open to attacks, but this is only for local use, and I will be added this kinda stuff in once it has all the functionality. Thanks again for your answer :)

Comment: $l = array_shift(license); If the keys aren't the same.

Answer (score 0):

correct me if I am wrong but I believe your problem would be solved by simply moving your query statement to after the first for loop...